# YouTube PHP Wrapper

Tags: php, youtube, wrapper

Is there any YouTube php wrapper that I can use to retrieve video's rating by their id?

Comment: *(tutorial)* [Use the YouTube API with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/), 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Zend/Google's PHP library. From Zend's  [Zend_Gdata_YouTube](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html) documentation:

```
<?php
  $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient,
                         $applicationId,
                         $clientId,
                         $developerKey);
?>
```

From the (perhaps better documented) [Google site](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Retrieving_Video_Entry):

```
<?php
  $videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs');
  echo 'Rating: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoRatingInfo() . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the YouTube provided sample codes:
[youtube/api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/README.md)